# Rolling Maximum in R

Tags: r, simulation

Is there a rolling maximum function in R that does not require a time series object? I want to simulate reflected Brownian motion, which one can simulate by having Y = Brownian Motion - Maximum of the Brownian motion up to that time. Now say I can simulate Brownian Motion (this is trivial) and I have a series of random times (so not integer times because I want to simulate a continuous time process), how do I find the maximum up till say time 10? For clarity my code so far is:

`brownian = function(n=1000, fun=rnorm) {x=cumsum(fun(n))}
X= brownian()
t=cumsum(abs(sin(seq(1:1000)))) %these are the random times`

Now, I would ideally like to write Y= X - .... but can't use any time series arguments b/c TS objects require even time spacing. How would I do this?

Comment: Two comments:  first, if you're happy with `cummax`, then it's not a "rolling" maximum you're after.  Second, what's the opposition to coercing your vector to an `xts` object and using `rollapply`?  One of the many great things about `R` is how easy it is to coerce from one class to another and back again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x - cummax(x)
```

Comment: Nice. Were `cummax` and `cummin` recently added?  In my two years workng with R I was never aware of them. :)

Comment: Don't know exactly when it was introduced.  I do know that R 2.6.0 had it.